# Google visualization api throws error when calling getImageURI in apps script

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I want to get the PNG URL for a column chart, however when I call getImageURI function the next error is thrown: " Object [object Object] has no method 'getImageURI' ".

This error is only thrown within *Apps Script*, if I copy and paste my code in a HTML file works fine.

Here my code:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
        ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', ],
        ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],
        ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
        ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
        legend: 'none',
      };

      var chart_div = document.getElementById('divGrafica');
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);

      // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
        console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
      });

      chart.draw(data, options);
```

Is not implemented getImageURI in Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

The GViz API is not officially supported in HtmlService, and therefore various functions may not work as expected.